# How to add an event to a ImageButton when is created on C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to generate a table with a ImageButton on each row.

The rows depends of a Query that i made from a calendar object.

My problem is when i generate my imagebutton, i can't set the "onClick" event to fire a method inside the class.

This is my code:

```
ImageButton test = new ImageButton();
test.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(borraCita);
test.ImageUrl = "~/Images/jumo.png";
test.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
```

Again, thanks :)

Comment: Row of what? If you are using a GridView you would be better off defining the button there (in markup), since you can assign the event there easily.

Comment: You don't have to set `OnClick` in the markup since you are already adding a handler in code with `Click`.

Comment: Also, you don't have to add `runat=server` in code, that's done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this wouldn't work. Did you add it to the page?

```
this.form1.Controls.Add(test);
```

Also, are you seeing any JS errors? Have you evaluated with Firebug? We may need more code to assist you as I see no reason why that shouldn't work.

Are you doing this in the PreInit method of the code-behind for the page? If not you may want to put the logic there because anything dynamic after that is going to be ignored.

Comment: not really  after PreInit everything will be ignored
Page_Init is the last place when u can add dynamic control from codebehing in asp.net pages life cycle;)
You can write like this as well 
`this.Controls.Add(test);` it's mean the same as @Tony write

Answer (score 0):

Your server side click handler is already set to `borraCita`, using the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.click.aspx) event. Also, you don't need to add an attribute for `runat=server`.

```
ImageButton test = new ImageButton();
// this is your server side click handler:
test.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(borraCita); 
test.ImageUrl = "~/Images/jumo.png";

// add the image to the appropriate control:
someControl.Controls.Add(test);
```

If you need to add a client side event handler, you can use [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick.aspx):

```
test.OnClientClick= "someJavascriptFunction();";
```